# Redirecting exec in the script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Can you explain the mechanism behind the following line in a script?

```
exec > >(tee logfile.txt)
```

this basically outputs both STDOUT to the console and also logfile.txt when it's in a script.  I know what it does, but I cannot explain exactly why it works the way it does. I understand >(command args) is a process substitution.  My main confusion comes from why having extra ">"?
why not exec >(tee logfile.txt)?

Comment: It splits stdout to the file and to the current stdout.  Often, the current stdout is a tty, but it is best to get out of the habit of thinking of stdout as always being the tty (console).  It sometimes is, but very often is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the help for `exec` (`$ help exec`). The relevant part is

> If COMMAND is not specified,
>       any redirections take effect in the current shell.

Since each command inherits its standard output from the shell that spawns it,
every command now has the given process substitution as its standard output, rather
than the terminal.

Comment: This means you can do `exec > file` to redirect stdout, and in this particular case, `file` is the process substitution `>(tee logfile.txt)` which is why you end up with two `>`s